# Using Ridley Gem to show Chef items

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to build a web app with Ruby on Rails and I need a page to that reports all the nodes on my chef server and figure out if they have a certain cookbook in their runlist or not. I am using the Ridley gem to connect to my chef server but i'm still new to ruby and having a hard time understanding how to use it.

his is the code I have so far:

```
ridley = Ridley.from_chef_config(‘/path/to/local/knifeconfig/knife.rb')
@ridleyresult = ridley.search(:node,"recipe:ge_role_secure_os")
```

And it keeps returning something like this:

```
<Ridley::NodeObject:0x007fef2ca88860>
<Ridley::NodeObject:0x007fef2ca99c50>
<Ridley::NodeObject:0x007fef2caa0a50>
<Ridley::NodeObject:0x007fef2cabb9b8>
<Ridley::NodeObject:0x007fef2cac07d8>
```

Anyone have any examples of trying to do something similiar?

Comment: Sorry this is what I get in return #<Ridley::NodeObject:0x007feed63c3a08>

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting back is a Node object and if you look into the properties of that you will find an attribute called "runlist" which will provide you with the cookbooks and recipes. Here is the code snippet:

```
node_name = 'xyz.abc.net'
run_list = ridley.node.find(node_name).run_list
p run_list
```